# deleteRecord on newly created record that errors

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

How can I completely delete are record that has errored:

for example:

```
user.one 'becameError', =>
  @send 'flashError', 'An error has occurred and the invitation cannot be sent.'
  user.deleteRecord()

user.get('transaction').commit()
```

The above errors with the all to familiar error:

> Attempted to handle event `deleteRecord` on
>    while in state rootState.error.
>   Called with undefined

The App.User.all() contains all records, isNew, isError.

How do I get rid of the damn thing?